# Adding Service Reference with encoding=ISO-8859-1 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, soap

I have a autogenerated webservice that i need to consume so that i may be able to create an application form. the problem is, when i am trying to add the webservice, it has an error

```
There was an error downloading 'http://bmctest016:8080/ctmbpi/TEST/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: %2Fctmbpi%2FTEST%2F%5Fvti%5Fbin%2FListData%2Esvc%2F%24metadata+Not+Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://bmctest016:8080/ctmbpi/TEST'.
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<html>
<head>
<title>Error 500 com/sun/messaging/AdministeredObject</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2><pre>com/sun/messaging/AdministeredObject</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/ctmbpi/TEST</p>
<p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p>
'.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I noticed that it fails to download the metadata from the webservice and as per checking with the autogenerated webservice. The encoding was ISO-8859-1 and as per research, Visual Studio 2013 recognizes UTF-8 webservice right?

Is it possible to change the settings in visual studio to read and identify the webservice encoded with ISO-8859-1? I still don't know how to change the autogenerated webservice to be encoded to UTF-8 so that visual studio will recognizes it.

P.S. The webservice is working fine and has succeeded multiple testing. Also, the webservice is identifiable by SoapUI Tool.

Thanks all

Comment: Why do you think this is an encoding problem??

Comment: Try opening 'http://bmctest016:8080/ctmbpi/TEST/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' in a browser and see the full error message.

Comment: i just assumed that the encoding is not compatible with visual studio that's why it fails to download the metadata @JakobOlsen, is a possibility for my error?

Comment: @JakobOlsen, i tried to open the said url and i got this error 

(HTTP ERROR: 404

/ctmbpi/TEST/_vti_bin/ListData.svc Not Found
RequestURI=/ctmbpi/TEST/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

Powered by Jetty://)

Comment: I don't think it is an encoding problem. The error you get is a http 404, which means that the page you are requesting from the server can not be found. That is why i wanted you to open it in a browser instead. If you can't even see the metadata in a browser you can not expect Visual Studio to grab it.

Comment: I see.. then it is on the autogenerated webservice tool's end? it is autogenerated by the BMC software

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Web Reference instead of a Service Reference:

> Add Service Reference -> Advanced... -> Add Web Reference... -> Set WSDL / URL -> Add Referece

[image]

Then, set the request encoding:

```
WS client = new WS();
client.RequestEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```